# shouldn't dbinom() and rbinom() match here in R?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, categorical-data

Perhaps this is too simple of a question, but shouldn't `dbinom()` and `rbinom()`in the example below match?

**P.S.** it seems like the vertical bars produced by `lines()` need an additive constant of `1` to shift to the right and match the open circles, is this because of `lines()` command?

**Here is the `R` code:**

```
a <- dbinom(0:25, 25, .5) # pmf of a binomial distribution with 25 trials
b <- rbinom(1e6, 25, .5)  # random binomial variates with 25 trials

plot(a)     # produces Open Circles
lines(table(b)/length(b), type = "h") # produces vertical bars
```

[image]

Comment: Look at your open circles.  Look at the one above x=5.  Count how many there are to the left.  What is the x-value for your first open circle?  What should it be?  What implicit assumption were you making when you called `plot(a)`?

Comment: If you count the number of circles you have 26, but only 25 bars. The circles are starting at 1 and not zero.  Plot a using this:`plot(y=a, x=0:25)`

Comment: @Dason, aha, the `rbinom()` has not sampled any `0`s or `1`s and no `24`s and `25`s. But can you possibly provide an example in which `rbinom()` results could match the `dbinom()` results?

Comment: It's not actually your rbinom stuff that is messing things up.  Both my and @Dave2e's comment point you toward your first plot statement.

Comment: @Dason, thank you so much got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot `dbinom` starts at 0 but you have not told R as much, so it assumes the densities start at X=1. On the other hand, the `lines.table` method looks at the rownames of the table and, if they're numeric, uses them as arguments to the X axis which starts the horizontal bars at X=0.

My suggested modification is:

`plot(0:25, a)`

instead.

Comment: It's actually their circles that are off.  Your example will have the same problem too.  `plot(a)` since it isn't given any input for x will assume x starts at 1.  Take a look at `plot(rnorm(3))` to see that it implicitly assumes x=1:3 and uses the output of rnorm(3) as the value for y.

Comment: @Dason true! I guess lines.table was working provided you wanted to start `x` at 0. I will revise.